# Parse HTML String to DOM and convert it back to string

Tags: javascript, html, string, parsing, domparser

I've got an `HTML` `string` e.g. `'<p><span class="text">Hello World!</span></p>'`

I parse this `HTML` `string` to `DOM` using `DOMParser().parseFromString()`, because I want to change the `innerHTML` of some specific `elements`. That's why I `parse` the `HTML` `string` to `DOM` and with `getElementByClassName` I get all my elements and loop through them to change it `innerHTML`. This works so far.

After I changed the `innerHTML`, I try to convert the new `DOM` back to a `string`. I can't figure out how. What I tried is to assign the `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` (tried both) to a variable like this:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString("<p>Hello World!</p>", "text/html");
console.log(doc.innerHTML) // undefined
console.log(doc.outerHTML) // undefined
```

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString("<p>Hello World!</p>", "text/html");
console.log(doc.innerHTML) // undefined
console.log(doc.outerHTML) // undefined
```

I always get `undefined`. How can I parse it back to a `string`? I found a lot examples with `innerHTML` or `outerHTML`, but in my case something went wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing `()` from the new DOMParser(). Should be `(new DOMParser()).parseFromString(...)`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

DOMParser will always give you a *document* in return. Documents don't have an `innerHTML` property, but the `document.documentElement` does, just like in a page's normal `document` object:

```js
const myHtmlString = '<p><span class="text">Hello World!</span></p>'
const htmlDom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(myHtmlString, 'text/html');
console.log(htmlDom.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

Do note that a `<head>` and `<body>` will be created for you, if you don't pass those tags in yourself. If you only want the body, then:

```js
const myHtmlString = '<p><span class="text">Hello World!</span></p>'
const htmlDom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(myHtmlString, 'text/html');
console.log(htmlDom.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Note that if you don't want the full document overhead, you can also just use a dummy "parent" element and assign its innerHTML value, a la ```let helper = document.createElement(`section`); helper.innerHTML = yourHTMLString; const domNode = helper.childNodes[0];```.

Comment: Possible, but that can result in arbitrary code execution, unlike DOMParser.

Comment: Absolutely, never use this for user-generated content.