# How to retrieve a DIV element from [object HTMLDivElement]?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using local storage to store a div element. However in the end I want to retrieve that div element from local storage, but every time I do that, I get back the output:
"[object HTMLDivElement]", which is a string

Is there any way to convert this received result into an HTML element, so that I can get the same div, that I stored at the beginning?

Comment: No, the data type is final. It needs to be a string. If you would like to keep reference of an element, you would need to go about it differently. Perhaps explain why you need to do this for a more mature answer.

Answer (score 1):

A good idea would be to transform the DOM object into a pure HTML string and then save it to local storage.

Look at this for further info:
[Parse HTML String to DOM and convert it back to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57074776/parse-html-string-to-dom-and-convert-it-back-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

localStorage [can only store strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#description). You can't store DOM nodes in it, JS will just go "yeah that doesn't work, let me convert it to a string first" and will use the generic "object type in brackets" string.

If you want to store an HTML element, don't store the element itself but store its [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) source code, which *is* a string.

```
// convert page element to string:
function storeElement(element, keyName) {
  localStorage.setItem(keyName, element.outerHTML);
}

// reconstitute the page element from string:
function retrieveElement(keyName, preserve=false) {
  const stored = localStorage.getItem(keyName);
  if (!preserve) localStorage.removeItem(keyName);
  const helper = document.createElement(`section`);
  helper.innerHTML = stored;
  return helper.childNodes[0];
}
```